# LibGDX creating (desktop) platform runnable

Tags: libgdx, executable, launcher

I want to export may project (game) to different desktop platforms. I exported it from eclipse (on Windows) and I get JAR file. On my machine I can start it, but on other it won't work. I guess JRE is missing there.

So, I followed LibGDX instructions how to deploy on different platforms:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Deploying-your-application

But when I run that packr.jar app I get following output:

```
D:\packing>java -jar packr.jar windows.json
Output directory 'D:\packing\windows' exists, deleting
Unpacking JRE
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
copying resources
minimizing JRE
unpacking rt.jar
packing rt.jar
Done!
```

After that I really get my exe file, all together with jre dir, my original game jar file and some config.json file, but that exe file just won't run. No failure message, just won't run. Any idea what's going on here? Or maybe there is some other tool for packing jar files?

All I need is to make my game runnable on desktop platforms: Windows, Mac & Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved this.

So I've found out that if I run exe file from console (cmd) and redirect output to file I can have some error report regarding the run attempt. So I did that:

```
myapp.exe > log.txt
```

and get log this log file:

```
Loading JVM runtime library ...
Passing VM options ...
  # -Xmx1G
Creating Java VM ...
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to load ZIP library: D:\packing\windows\jre\bin\zip.dll
```

Zip file was there, but something was wrong with it so I replaced it with one I had in my Java installation (my was larger). After that I was able to run exe file well.

Answer (score 2):

For windows OS you could use something like [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) which simply puts a wrapper around your jar file.

It also has the capability to provide a given jre. So your users do not need to have one installed.